# Get Number Grouping with Regex

Tags: regex

I have strings that look like this:

```
get_a_string_A14_for_1.23.87.19_A12_and_others
get_a_string_A14_for_1.23.827.19_A12_and_others
get_a_string_A14_for_1.23.87.1_A12_and_others
get_a_string_A14_for_2.23.87.19_A12_and_others
```

I want to pull the numbers `1.23.87.19`, `1.23.827.19`, `1.23.87.1`, and `2.23.87.19`. The numbers will change, but this is the basic structure of the numbers.

I have tried doing:

```
([0-9]\.[0-9])
[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,4}
[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,4}
[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]
```

And more, but have not had any luck. Can someone please help, and explain what I need to do to get these number groupings?

Comment: Based on what you've tried, you can do this way: \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB3vR7/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
[0-9]+         # Match 1 OR more digits
(?:            # start of non-capturing group
\.             # match a literal dot
[0-9]+         # Match 1 OR more digits
)              # group close
(?:\.[0-9]+)+  # Match 1 OR more of the expression in the group
```

Comment: The explanation is really helpful.